# asp.net vb2010 How to log Windows Authentication events - i.e. save user name and login time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, windows-authentication

Just now getting into the asp.net environment with VB 2010. I have designed an intranet page that we will be using to auction off old equipment to employees. I've had some very good luck getting the whole thing working, but I have hit a snag on one minor issue: I would like to keep a database table of user logins and times.

Several methods have presented themselves, but so far none of them have been adequate. The main problem seems to be that regardless of the event I use to record the login, they fire multiple times resulting in as many as 4 or 5 entries in the login database for the same login event, not to mention additional times when something on the page changes for whatever reason.

The system uses Windows Authentication, so the user must login with his/her company credentials.

I can't remember what all I have tried, but the first thing I tried was the `Page_Load` event because it seemed obvious. I've learned that because the page updates the display every ten seconds, `Page_Load` event fires numerous times throughout the session.

Fighting my way through other ideas, all of which failed, I came to the `WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` event in the `Global_asax` class, shown below:

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
--------------------------------------------
Public Sub WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs)

        Dim strLoginName = args.Identity.Name
        Dim sqlCommandString As String = "INSERT into tblLogin (UserLogin,DateTime) VALUES ('" & _
                strLoginName & "','" & _
                Format(Now, "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "');"
        Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
        Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConn)
        sqlCommand.Connection.Open()
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlCommand.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

which also seems to fire multiple times. I then tried to work a way where setting a Boolean value to TRUE upon authentication so that the data would be written to the database only once:

```
    Public Sub WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs)

    If Not boolUserIsLoggedIn Then
        boolUserIsLoggedIn = True

        Dim strLoginName = args.Identity.Name
        Dim sqlCommandString As String = "INSERT into tblLogin (UserLogin,DateTime) VALUES ('" & _
                strLoginName & "','" & _
                Format(Now, "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "');"
        Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
        Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConn)
        sqlCommand.Connection.Open()
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlCommand.Connection.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

and subsequent authentication iterations would skip the database write code; but then I needed to find a way to clear the Boolean value when the user logged off or closed the session. I couldn't figure out how to trap a "Logged Off" event, and the `Session_End` and `Application_End` events didn't work as I had hoped.

I feel like this is getting too convoluted to make sense. To put it simply, I just need a way to record a user's login name and date only once per session. Can anyone help?

[Edit: Although this is not really an essential element of the page, it has become a crusade for me to get it to work if not for any other reason than to understand the process.]

Comment: That technique for building sql statements is horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: As an example, try entering the following in for the username: ` ');DROP TABLE tblLogin;--`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Aww, you could have said to backup the database first. That way the OP gets to learn how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I might be a little more concerned about that if this were a public website. This is strictly intranet, and there's no access outside our network. And this is really more of a learning exercise for me anyway. But your points are well taken, thanks!

Comment: Also, it uses the Windows authentication, so there's no login process.

Comment: Following up on the injection attack angle, I did a little bit of research, and found this page :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx. This may not be the entire scope of the nature of protection, but based on that I added these lines:        /If txtBidItem1.Text.Contains("'") Or txtBidItem1.Text.Contains("--") Or txtBidItem1.Text.Contains("1=1") Then/
            txtBidItem1.Text = ""/
            Exit Sub/
        End If/ I do have textboxes where bidders enter their bids. Would this be adequate?

Comment: @BillNorman NO NO NO. That is **not** how your project against sql injection. The key phrase to google for is "`Parameterized queries`"

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Most of what I am seeing online about parameterizing relates to queries. Is it necessary when executing INSERT commands? In my application the only user input is a bid amount, and even though I have managed to put together a working INSERT procedure using parameterized values, I wonder if it's even necessary, since it uses ExecuteNonQuery. And again, thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @BillNorman An INSERT query could still lead to an SQL injection attack. Or just a plain error if an apostrophe is included. If you always use SQL parameters, then you will mostly not have to be concerned about that. Useful reading: [SQL Injection – a Serious Security Issue](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection).

Comment: It's definitely necessary for INSERT statements

Answer (score 2):

Researching more about JDB's suggestion using the session ID property, I discovered another property that seems to be doing exactly what I need: The `IsNewSession` property.

With that in mind, I have this code in my default.aspx's Page_Load event:

```
If Context.Session.IsNewSession Then
        Login()
    End If
```

Which calls the Login sub that writes the login information to the database:

```
   Protected Sub Login()
    Dim strConnectionString As String = "Data Source = toponet\sqlexpress; initial catalog = TopoAuction; Integrated security = True"

    Dim strLoginName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    Dim sqlCommandString As String = "INSERT into tblLogin (UserLogin,DateTime) VALUES ('" & _
            strLoginName & "','" & _
            Format(Now, "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "');"
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConn)
    sqlCommand.Connection.Open()
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlCommand.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

So far, testing has shown that it fires only once per session. Even if the browser moves to another site and comes back, it will not count that as a new session. This seems to be the perfect solution.

I'm open to hear any comments or concerns about this, anybody?

Comment: There are some cases where you can accidentally create a new session, but it doesn't sound like the occasionaly re-login is going to be problematic for you.

Comment: That's true, JDB. The objective is to not log a login every ten seconds that the page is open.

Answer (score 0):

I think, perhaps, you are getting hung up on the request/response cycle of a web page. If you have only ever used WebForms and come from a desktop development background, the [statelessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) of the HTTP protocol can be very confusing.

Essentially, the client (the browser) requests information from the server (where your .NET code is running). Each request is completely independent from every other request - the server maintains no memory of prior requests.

Now, WebForms was an attempt to bridge the gap by shoe-horning on a sort of pseduo-statefullness on top of HTTP. This is where ViewState and other similar concepts come in. Basically, WebForms includes additional information about the state of the web application in each Response, which is then included again in following Requests, maintaining the application's state and giving the appearance of statefulness. There are other tricks too, like server variables, which can be used to maintain some "memory" of past transactions.

However, this statefulness is easily broken. For example, if you include a basic anchor tag (not an ASP.NET server control), and you redirect to another page (or even the same page) without including the view state, then you will lose some of your application state. Even if you *are* using server controls and maintaining your view state, you must pay careful attention to the [WebForms Page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). If you are handling the wrong event (such as Page_Load) or attempting to access a property at the wrong time (before the web page has had a chance to reload it's state), you may not get the results you are expecting.

In this scenario, I recommend you check the user's [Session ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It changes very infrequently. If you have a user ID coming in with a session ID you've not seen before (or that's not been associated with that user in some amount of time - say 30 minutes), then you probably have a unique logon event. If you *have* seen that user ID/Session ID combo, then that user has probably already "logged in" and you don't need to record it again.

Alternatively, just store the user's login state in a [session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can check that variable on each Page_Load and branch (using an `If` statement) based on your needs.

Comment: In trying to learn more about Session ID, I discovered what seems to be the simplest answer to my question. I will post it in my "Answer Your Question" below. But I credit you, JDB, for setting me in the right direction. Thanks!